# How to run another event based on click event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to run a `change` event when user click a button.

```
$('#b1').on('click', function(){
    $('#select_item').trigger('change');
});

$('#select_item').on('change', function(){

    var jbyr = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

    if(jbyr == 1){
       alert('Option 1');
    }
    else if(jbyr == 2){
       alert('Option 2');
    }
    else{
       alert('Option 3');
    }
});
```

What I am looking for is when I click button, the combobox change its option from previously 1 to 2 for example and fire the `select_item` change script so the `alert('Option 2')` is displayed.

addition:

`#b1` is a button, not submitting anything. It just force changes the combobox option to option 2. When the combobox change by the button click, the combobox change event should fired. So, user not touch the combobox

Comment: So what doesn't work?

Comment: no alert is displayed

Comment: Have you verified that the click event processes?  Have you verified that `$('#select_item')` finds an element?

Comment: What is `#b1` ?

Comment: It will be quite annoying to have a `change` handler on the `select` element if the user is also able to change the `select` element themselves. Do you want the `select` to only be changeable via button?

Comment: Just tested it, selecting an option triggers an alert displaying the selected option, clicking button alerts the selected option. Am I missing something?

Comment: From the logic I'm assuming it's a selector error, or a binding error.

Comment: Dynamic elements here?

Comment: I'd like to force the user selected certain combobox option when press the button `#b1`

Comment: @Shota please verify that the click handler logic executes when it should, and also verify that the selector for the secondary element finds a match.

Comment: So you want to force or simulate some "user" inputted changes... And is `#b1` a `submit` ? What happens on click?

Comment: `#b1` is a button, not submitting anything. It just force changes the combobox option to option 2. When the combobox change by the button `click`, the combobox `change` event should fired. So, user not touch the combobox.

Comment: What stands out of your code, is on `#b1` click, based on the value of `#select_item` value, something should happens. -- Where does it stuck?

Comment: What is the intend? Is it like a button to set a "pre-defined" selection? Like a master button to change other user inputs?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette 'not predefined' or default. The button change the combox option dynamically.

Comment: *«The button change the combox option dynamically.»* -- Hew...  Based on you code, seems like you need an alias on click to trigger a change on something else. So... Change event to apply on **already done changes** made by the user - That is what you have as code for now... Please edit your question with your actual code and what you intend to do... Not what your failing solution does... That is called [**X/Y problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: well, of course it's just an example. I just can't copy paste the whole page here. In the code example I change the combobox to option 2 (fixed). It's simplified, so, what I'd like want to know is how to change combobox value  and fire the event based on it's option value when user click a button

Comment: Reflecting on Fecosos's comment about testing it and it working, and as far as I can tell from looking at the script I could replicate it working also, the real question here is why it is not working for you.  Which is related to me asking if you have verified things, which has not been responded to.

Comment: A `change` event is just an event. It does not actually change anything. It just reads elements state.

Comment: @Taplar button is fine. Select is also fine (when not using button click).

Comment: So if you select one, the alert happens?

Comment: yes. the alert is displayed

Comment: And a console log in the button click event handler prints out?

Comment: Yes. it's print out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a simple case of *do it the hard way*.  There is no reason, since you own both pieces of subscription code, to trigger any events what so ever.  So don't do that, just encapsulate the change code into a new function.  Also I highly recommend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript - Philip Walton @ Google Engineer](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-alert').on('click', function() {
    onSelectedChanged($('.js-select'));
  });

  $('.js-select').on('change', function() {
    onSelectedChanged($(this));
  });
  
  function onSelectedChanged($element){
    var jbyr = $element.find('option:selected').val();

    if (jbyr == 1) {
      alert('Option 1');
    } else if (jbyr == 2) {
      alert('Option 2');
    } else {
      alert('Option 3');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="button" value="click me" class="js-alert" />
<select class="js-select">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2" selected>Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain about the coding need of triggering a `change` event on `click`...

***"Cascading events"*** sure is not the idea of the year.

---

What I can say from here is you to define a **function** to call either on `click` or `change` of the elements you like.

So just create a named function:

```
myFunction(){
  //Do whatever...
}
```

Then call `myFunction()` in the event handler you like:

```
$(element).on("click",myFunction);
```

or:

```
$(element).on("change",myFunction);
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to set the the value of the combobox like this.

```
$('#b1').on('click', function () {
    $('#select_item').val(2);
    $('#select_item').trigger('change');
});

$('#select_item').on('change', function () {

    var jbyr = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

    if (jbyr == 1) {
        alert('Option 1');
    } else if (jbyr == 2) {
        alert('Option 2');
    } else {
        alert('Option 3');
    }
});
```

Comment: You do not have to change a value to *logically* trigger a change event.

Comment: @Taplar please show me a solution that will trigger the change handler without triggering the change event manually when removing this.  $('#select_item').trigger('change');

Comment: The argument was about `$('#select_item').val(2);`... I think

Comment: Yes.  The solution suggested that you must change the value before triggering the event.  This is not true.

Comment: You're example does not make sense.

Comment: That is a common practice if you want to not only establish an event handler for an element, but also run the logic on page load.  In any case, the event does happen and is processed, which shows that the changing of a value is **not** required to trigger an event logically, which is the only difference between this solution and the snippet in the OP

Comment: Many things are unlogical in this thread. Like the attempt to trigger a change on click... The issue is **Why**.